# Using WebWorkers just for LocalStorage?

Tags: html, local-storage, web-worker

Recently, on CoderWall https://coderwall.com/p/rkls8g:

> *Make use of Web Workers*
>
> *When it comes to do synchronous stuff like using the LocalStorage or
>   XMLHttpRequest, It's way better to make use of workers to do jobs in a
>   non-blocking manner ...*

Is there really a need? For AJAX, since its already async, there seem no need to introduce more overheads of using WebWorkers?

For LocalStorage, the argument is that

> *LocalStorage's API writes all data directly into filesystem, so it has to lock the file. and it's done synchronously*

Is this really slow? Since I'd expect only 1 application (ur browser) to write to LocalStorage for your domain, it isn't likely to block isit? LocalStorage is capped at only 5MB? The only situation I see a long waiting time to write to LocalStorage is perhaps if you have multiple tabs/browser accessing the same web app and writing tons of stuff? Even so, I suppose it should be cached, hopefully a write back cache, then it should be fast again?

Comment: "synchronous stuff like XHR". That is: Setting the async flag to false (`xhr.open('method', 'url', false);`. localStorage's allegedly bad performance is overrated, I have never run into issues with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe most browsers will [implement web storage](http://code.google.com/p/webkit-mirror/source/browse/Source/WebCore/storage/StorageMap.cpp) as in memory storage. So you won't get performance benefit over using web worker.

To handle multiple tabs/browser you will use [storage events](http://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/#the-storage-event).

As you can see, localStorage is not slow, but in-consistant sometimes on read and write. It is nothing you can do except to use transactional storage like IndexedDB or WebSQL.